# Spring Kafka JsonSerializer usage

Tags: java, spring, serialization, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to follow the instructions here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_serialization_deserialization_and_message_conversion

To set up a KafkaTemplate that can serialize and send some simple Java POJOs that I have. But I found the documentation vague and confusing, especially this part:

> For this purpose Spring for Apache Kafka also provides
>   JsonSerializer/JsonDeserializer implementations based on the Jackson
>   JSON processor. When JsonSerializer is pretty simple and just lets to
>   write any Java object as a JSON byte[]
>
> ...
>
> Although
>   Serializer/Deserializer API is pretty simple and flexible from the
>   low-level Kafka Consumer and Producer perspective, it is not enough on
>   the Messaging level, where KafkaTemplate and @KafkaListener are
>   present.
>
> ...
>
> The MessageConverter can be
>   injected into KafkaTemplate instance directly and via
>   AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory bean definition for the
>   @KafkaListener.containerFactory() property

So my question is:

- What is the type of my KafkaTemplate? Is it `KafkaTemplate<String, Object>`? Or is it `KafkaTemplate<String, String>`?
- What is my
  Serializer class? Is it `StringSerializer`, or is it `JsonSerializer`?
- Do
  I use `kafkaTemplate.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter())` when creating my KafkaTemplate bean?

Apologies if these are stupid questions - I'm trying to understand the correct way of setting it up rather than "hacking it till it kinda works".

Comment: I was using Producer<> and Consumer<> from kakfa library. So while creating those, i used key and value serializers as (StringSerializer) from kafka library. I read in couple of blogs to use StringSerializer. Converted  json to string on inserting to queue and vice versa after reading the message).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `<String, Object>`
2. `JsonSerializer`
3. The message converter is only used when using the send that takes a `Message<?>` and with a `JsonSerializer` you should use the default one.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer! For Consumer (deserializing), is it the same in that I only need to use the MessageConverter if I want to receive Message<?> ?

Comment: It depends; if you are using `@KafkaListener`, `Message<?>`s are involved. See the apps from [my SpringOne talk](https://github.com/SpringOnePlatform2016/grussell-spring-kafka) for examples of using a `JsonDeserializer` Vs. message converter on the consuming side - specifically app5 and app6.